# Firebase in Swift. Cannot cast value of type 'NSNull' to 'NSDictionary'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Every time my app is opened being connected, an error is caused. I think I am casting values correctly as `[String: String]` but not. What is the correct way to solve this problem?

```
 class func info(forUserID: String, completion: @escaping (User) -> Swift.Void) {
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(forUserID).child("credentials").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        //This line is the reason of the problem. 
        let data = snapshot.value as! [String: String]
        let name = data["name"]!
        let email = data["email"]!
        let link = URL.init(string: data["profile"]!)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: link!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                let profilePic = UIImage.init(data: data!)
                let user = User.init(name: name, email: email, id: forUserID, profilePic: profilePic!)
                completion(user)
            }
        }).resume()
    })
}
```

The error says

> Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x1ae148588) to 'NSDictionary'
>   (0x1ae148128).

Comment: what does your json structure look like?

Comment: log the value of snapshot before the forced unwrap. Also avoid using force unwrapping in general - use `if let` or `guard` statements instead

Comment: The error message says that `snapshot.value` is `<NSNull>` (which is not the same as `nil`) and the cast to a dictionary fails.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I got it. The solution was to use if let statement. Also, in what situation it is good to use then?

Comment: @vadian how is it different for nil?

Comment: `nil` is no value. `NSNull` is an object / a valid class. An `NSNull` instance compared to `nil` is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

When a webservice returns a value of `<null>`, it's being represented as an `NSNull` object. That is an actual object and comparing it to `nil` will return `false`.

This is what I do:

```
if let json = snapshot.value as? [String: String] {
    //if it's possible to cast snapshot.value to type [String: String]
    //this will execute
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`FIRDataSnapshot` should return `Any?` upon successful request, on failure - it would return `null`. Because we don't know when the request will succeed or fail, we need to safely unwrap this optional. In your error, you forcefully downcast (`as!`), which will crash if the snapshot data is not returned as `[String: String]`, i.e. if your request returns `null`.  Conditionally downcasting (`as?`) safely returns `nil` if your snapshot data is not of type `[String: String]`

**TL;DR** - You need to conditionally downcast

```
// So rather than
let data = snapshot.value as! [String: String]

// Conditionally downcast
if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: String] {
     // Do stuff with data
}

// Or..
guard let data = snapshot.value as? [String: String] else { return }
// Do stuff with data
```